# How come this For Loop increments in this manner? (seems exponential)

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Javascript newbie here. I'm self-studying and now learning For Loops at this stage. I'm playing around with it by tweaking simple examples from Youtube tutorials. There's one I made that puzzles me a bit:

```
for (i = 0; i <=7; i+=1) {
    console.log(i);
    i += i;
    console.log(i);
}
```

And it prints out this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dHrz.png)

Given that I have two console.logs, I know that I need to look at two sets of numbers separately. The 0,1,3,7 and 0,2,6,14. Here I see some pattern in the results. The numbers increment by 2^0, then 2^1, then 2^2, then 2^3 etc

I've been stuck for a while making sense of this. But I really don't understand how my code causes that to happen. So I'd really appreciate any help to break the code down to explain the pattern.

Comment: `i += i` doubles `i`; i + i = 2i, and `i += i` is effectively equivalent to `i = i + i;` or `i = 2 * i`. Is that the part you’re asking about?

Comment: take out the `i += i;` part; the loop increments for you. If you want to count exponentially, use `i*=2` in the for statement for readability.

Comment: The code works perfectly fine. Try dry running your code by hand, maybe on a piece of paper. The `i+=i` is setting the value of `i` to twice it's value when it entered the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unrolling the loop to illustrate what others have already pointed out in the comments. You are incrementing `i` via the loop increment (as you should) but then also doubling it inside the loop every time. Here is what is happening from the `i` perspective:

```js
i = 0; // loop initialization
console.log(0);
i = 0 + 0;
console.log(0);
i = 0 + 1; // loop increment
console.log(1);
i = 1 + 1;
console.log(2);
i = 2 + 1; // loop increment
console.log(3);
i = 3 + 3;
console.log(6);
i = 6 + 1; // loop increment
// ...
```